# THREE js - Load texture from string data

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am uploading a bunch of png files to AWS, and fetching them as I need them. When uploading, I stream the data read through fs, and when downloading I pipe the data from AWS as a response.

Anyhow, when I get hold of the data on the client, it is returned as a string with the following structure:

```
�PNG


IHDR�x�� IDATx���_��[�����1���s�?��9u����h�...
```

How do I load this into a texture? I have tried with [this](https://jeanlescure.io/blog/solved-how-to-use-embedded-base64-image-data-as-texture-in-threejs/) (also recommended by mrdoob [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3430))

But it results in the Image throwing an uninformative error, and onload is never called.

```
let image = new Image();  
let texture = new THREE.Texture();

image.onerror = function(e) {
  //enters here
}

image.onload = function(e) {
  //never here
  texture.image = texture_image;
  texture.needsUpdate = true;
}

image.src = myFetchedPNGData;
```

What is the correct way to create a THREE.Texture out of this data?

**EDIT:**
Here is the request for fetching the data:

```
let requestt = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

request.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  // Here myFetchedPNGData recides in event.target.response
}, false);

request.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
  //do error handling
}, false);

onProgress && request.addEventListener('progress', (event) => {
  //Handle request
}, false);

request.send(...);
```

Comment: Added the request as requested ;)

Comment: What is the "uninformative error" you are getting? In your code, you are using the variable `texture_image` in the line `texture.image = texture_image`, should it not be `texture.image = image` ?

Comment: Also, in the `load` event listener, you are not doing anything, shouldn't you be assigning the response to image.src ?

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly, you are better off listing for the `onreadystatechange` of XMLHttpRequest as I think the load event is always called when the request is finished, event if an error occurred.